# How can I remove "xsi:type, "xmlns:xs" and "xmlns:xsi" from my XML generated from dataset.GetXml() in C#

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

This is how the dataSet is created, I am using the ExcelReaderFactory library for converting an Excel to a dataSet.

```
var dataSet = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fileStream).AsDataSet();
```

Then I delete the unused columns, rows, etc, and convert it to XML and return it.

```
                dataSet.DataSetName = "DTO";
                dataSet.Tables[0].TableName = "ExampleInterface";
                dataSet.Namespace = "";
                var xml = dataSet.GetXml();
                return Ok(new { xml = xml });
```

The output is

```
<DTO>\r\n  
    <Example>\r\n    
        <SampleDate xsi:type=\"xs:string\"
            xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"
            xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">2022-12-23
        </SampleDate>\r\n    
        <SampleNumber xsi:type=\"xs:double\"
            xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"
            xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">1
        </SampleNumber>\r\n  
    </Example>\r\n  
    ....
```

And the desired should be

```
<DTO>  
    <Example>   
        <SampleDate>2022-12-23
        </SampleDate>   
        <SampleNumber>1
        </SampleNumber> 
    </Example>
    ....
```

How can get I this?

Comment: It could be done via XSLT transformation.

Comment: Why remove useful schema that is used to validate types and make sure when file is read the xml string are converted to there correct numeric types.